# Laravel 5.2 Redirecting user based on user column

Tags: laravel, redirect, eloquent

I have a multiple step form. Every time a user completes one of the forms the currentStep column is updated. If the user does not complete all four forms before logging out, when they log back in they will be redirected to whatever step they left off on. Is overriding the authenticated method in my AuthController the best way to do this?

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user)
{
    if ($user->step === '1') {
        return redirect()->intended('reg/step2');
    }

    return redirect()->intended('/');
}
```

Comment: No. use middleware instead

Answer (score 0):

Yes using `authenticated` method or overriding `redirectPath`method will be enough.

By the way, In my personal opinion, as suggested in the comment above; creating a middleware to implement a simple functional requirement like:

> "The software shall redirect the users to the step which they left off only when they login back to the software."

is over engineering which we should avoid. As you can already see, laravel itself uses a method in a trait to redirect the user after a successful login. Not a middleware.

see the last line (from v.5.1 LTS):

```
/**
 * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  bool  $throttles
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
{
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
        return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::user());
    }

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```